# Powershell - Attach the contents of a text file in quotes to a variable in another script or file?

Tags: powershell, base64

I'm trying to base64 a log collector exe and place the base64text in a variable in a separate script to decode.

This is my code to base64-

```
$SourceFile = "C:\Users\Downloads\GrabEventLogs.exe"
$B64File       = "C:\Users\Downloads\GrabEventLogsB64.txt"

[IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($B64File,[char[]][Convert]::ToBase64String([IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($SourceFile)))
```

And then I wanted to take the contents of the "GrabEventLogsB64.txt" and add it to a variable in quotes at the top of another script like this -

```
### I need to add Base64text here as 
$B64File = "contents of GrabEventLogsB64.txt"
```

I've been doing a workaround with cat and bash but how do I do it with powershell?

So, basically, how do grab the contents of a text file
$B64File = "C:\Users\Downloads\GrabEventLogsB64.txt"
and place after a variable in quotes in a script, or separate file.

```
### I need to add Base64text here as 
$B64File = "contents of GrabEventLogsB64.txt"
```

Thanks!!

Comment: If you want to get the content of a file you use `Get-Content`. ‍♂️ ... or you use the same method you used to read the content of the executable file.

Comment: Ah, I'm trying to create one final file...so the base64 will have to already be inside the final file.  I won't have access to the others when I run it.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. Please read the help  including the examples [Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you don't want to not just call the contents of that txt file from the second script, for instance :

`$B64File = Get-Content GrabEventLogsB64.txt`

you want to insert it into there so the string itself is within your script?

Only way I can think of would be to have a place holder string within your second script, then use `Get-Content` both the txt file and the 2nd .ps1 into variables, and use `Replace()` to replace the holding string with the contents of the .txt file. So assuming the second script contained

```
### I need to add Base64text here as 
$B64File = "contents of GrabEventLogsB64.txt"
```

then you could have something like

```
$B64File = Get-Content GrabEventLogsB64.txt -Raw -Encoding Byte
$SecondScript = Get-Content MySecondScript.ps1
$SecondScript.Replace("contents of GrabEventLogsB64.txt",$B64File) | Set-Content MySecondScript.ps1 -Force -Encoding Byte
```

Note, while I suspect you'll need to ensure the correct encoding is used to get the desired result, I'm not certain what I've suggested will do the job so experimentation may be required.

Comment: It seems that the OP does not want to keep the file containing the Base64 value. The OP wants the value hardcoded in the second script.